# Bind Dataset to ASP.Net Div tag using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Iam Binding <%#Eval("message") %> inside Div tag.Now iam fetching data from db using dataset inside repeater .Each time page is loading fetching data from db which i want to avoid.So i decided to use Jquery ajax to bind dataset.My problem is how can we bind dataset inside div tag.

My code is :

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="rep_ItemDataBound">   <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <p><%#Eval("message") %></p>
        </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetMessages()
    {
        string query = "GetMessageData";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }
    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionng"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "welcome.aspx/GetMessages",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
   --Iam stuck Here--
```

}

So if success how can i bind my dataset to div tag inside repeater.

Comment: Why not removing the repeater?

Comment: Hi the application is like posting messages.So if i post messages ,it gets stored in db and fetched back by repeater by binded messages ordered by posted date. Earlier i used to bind in repeater  using dataset  in code behind like      rep.DataSource = this.GetMessages();               rep.DataBind().But each time while posting messages it  is using page load and fetching data and binding it with repeater which i don't need.Hence i decided to use jquery ajax method to bind data inside repeater but i stuck at the line in the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really have to do is loop through the XML returned by the `$.ajax` call and append the results to an element on the page.

1.Add `<div id="result"></div>` anywhere on your page.We will write the output of the `$.ajax` call to this element.

2.Change your `OnSuccess()` function like this:

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var length = xmlDoc.children[0].children.length;
    $("#result").empty();

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var item = xmlDoc.children[0].children[i];
        var message = item.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].innerHTML;
        var div = "<div><p>" + message + "</p></div>";
        $("#result").append(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks ..I have edited my question with my detailed code.Can you pls look into it..

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to look into?I gave you the answer, all you have to do is copy and paste it into your solution and debug it